# PHP newbie: can't use a constant to define array

Tags: php, arrays, constants

This works fine:

```
$entity->field_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'value' => date_format($date),
  'timezone' => 'UTC',
  );
```

But I need to make it more generic, to allow for different field names. So I try to use a constant:

```
define('FIELD_TIME', 'field_time');
$entity->FIELD_TIME[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'value' => date_format($date),
  'timezone' => 'UTC',
  );
```

But this does not target the correct array name, which should be [field_time][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]

I also tried:

```
define('FIELD_TIME', 'field_time');
$entity->constant('FIELD_TIME')[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'value' => date_format($date),
  'timezone' => 'UTC',
   );
```

But that throws: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The value of the constant; only scalar and null values are allowed. Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values. It is possible to define resource constants, however it is not recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior. "

Comment: @Flosculus He did not want to use constant as array, but it's value. Let's say you have a class with property(array) = `public $_arr = array(...);` and in another file `define('BLA', '_arr');`. OP wants to do `$obj->_arr = ...` but using constant value => `$obj->BLA =`

Comment: If `FIELD_TIME` is a constant of the class, shouldn't it be accessed statically like `EntityClass::FIELD_TIME`?

Comment: @Flosculus It's a constant of a file than instantiates the class. You have `class Entity {
    public $field_time = null;
}
$entity = new Entity(); define('FIELD_TIME', 'field_time');`

Comment: Ah i get it.  It seems a little off however.  If the properties of the class need to be created dynamically, wouldn't something akin to Doctrine's `ArrayCollection` or even old fashioned magic be more suitable?

Comment: @Flosculus Yeah, but I think he already has property with name `field_time` and just need to push things to it. Really don't get the purpose of having constants with the class properties, but maybe there's a logic hidden there. We can wait the OP to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$entity->{FIELD_TIME}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = 'something';
```

Yes, just bracket the constant ! This also work for function calls

```
$entity->{FUNC_NAME_CONST}();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
define('FIELD_TIME', 'field_time');
$entity->constant('FIELD_TIME')[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'value' => date_format($date),
  'timezone' => 'UTC',
   );
```

This way should work, but as of PHP 5.4

Otherwise you will need one more line:

```
define('FIELD_TIME', 'field_time');
$field_time = constant('FIELD_TIME');
$entity->$field_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
'value' => date_format($date),
      'timezone' => 'UTC',
       );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

---

If I understood correctly, it should be used as:

```
class Entity {
    public $field_time = null;
}
$entity = new Entity();
/** 
* Instead of:
* $entity->field_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array('key' => 'val');
*/
define('FIELD_TIME', 'field_time');
$field_time = constant('FIELD_TIME');
// or $field_time = FIELD_TIME;
$entity->$field_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array('key' => 'val');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an array directly from the returnvalue of a method.

```
$entity->constant('FIELD_TIME')[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]
```

is wrong, store the return value of constant() first in another variable and access LANGUAGE_NONE via that array.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you good, you just want use the constant to call the correct array by its name?

```
define('FIELD_TIME', 'field_time');
$entity->{FIELD_TIME}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'value' => date_format($date),
  'timezone' => 'UTC',
  );
```

this works fine for me if you have a declared array with the name "field_time"